# Generating qooxdoo api and ignore errors

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

is it possible to generate a Qooxdoo API even if not all tags and comments are correct?

When i tried `generate.py api` i got a lot of errors. Can the generator ignore these errors?

== edit

I compared the [Qooxdoo documentation standard](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1/write_api_documentation#example) with our coding / spket standard docs.

Qooxdoo wants the documentation of parameters styled like

```
@param [name] {[type]} [description]
```

and Spket has the Style

```
@param {[type]} [name] [description]
```

even with line breaks between the name and the description. So the errors occour.

Why is there no possibility to ignore those missing parametername errors or even provide an other format?

== end edit

Thanks,
el

Comment: how can i re-format the @param definitions? I can not use spket for formating anymore if the format is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the generator only stops if you have done an error by the @param definition. But only if you do not define the parameter name:

```
/**
 * bla bla
 *
 * @param {String} bla bla
 */
test : function(test) { ... }
```

In this case the name for "test" is missing, the generator stops with an error like:

```
>>> Generating API data...
  - Loading class docs... 10% 20% 30% 40% 50% 60% 70% 80% 90% 100%
    - Failed: Missing name of parameter., Line: 78, Column: 12
!!! Error in API data of class: testapi.Application
!!! Found erroneous API information. Please see above. Stopping!
```

Just add the missing name (the error shows you the line in the file):

```
/**
 * bla bla
 *
 * @param test {String} bla bla
 */
test : function(test) { ... }
```

Now the generator doesn't stop, if you have done an other mistake, like a @return definition is missing, the generator creates the API Viewer and you will see the issue when you open the API Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the generation of the API should always work, even if you don't have a single thing documented. So the errors most come from some other circumstances. Maybe you should post the error message the generator produces so we can get that error out of the way.

Regards, Martin